# db_query for a specific titles

Tags: database

I'm building a custom module for webform and I want to get only a title for a specific content type.

In phpMyAdmin with sql query I've managed to sort what titles I need. This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT title FROM `node` WHERE TYPE = 'outlets' AND uid
```

How can I wrap this into db_query() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read more about [db_query() here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7).

```
$result = db_query("
  SELECT title
  FROM {node} n
  WHERE n.type = :type
    AND n.uid =:uid
", array(':type' => 'outlets', ':uid' => $uid));

foreach ($result as $record) {
  // Perform operations on $record->title, etc. here.
  // in this example the available data would be mapped to object properties:
  // $record->nid, $record->title, $record->created
}
```